# How to detect if a line/ray has been updated (its location been changed)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I defined/displayed a line in my code as following

```
indicator("line_changed",overlay = true)
price = input.price(0, "Price of Interest", inline="price", confirm=true)
time_ = input.time(0, "Time", inline="price", confirm=true)

if barstate.islast
    line.new(time_, price, time_ + 1, price, color=color.gray, extend=extend.right, xloc=xloc.bar_time)
```

Now I want to display if the location of the line is changed after the first time that I defined it.

I did it as following, but it is always false, not sure why. can someone let me know what I am doing wrong.

```
indicator("line_changed",overlay = true)
price = input.price(0, "Price of Interest", inline="price", confirm=true)
time_ = input.time(0, "Time", inline="price", confirm=true)


var line_changed = false
var first_price_line = price

if first_price_line!=price
    line_changed := true
if barstate.islast
    line.new(time_, price, time_ + 1, price, color=color.gray, extend=extend.right, xloc=xloc.bar_time)

    label.new(time_, price,  str.tostring(line_changed), xloc=xloc.bar_time)
```